# How to set a specific sorting order according to click using DxGrid Blazor?

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, devexpress, dxgrid

I have a DxGrid in Blazor, and the default approach it's:

Default state, qhen the user set the first click the column receive the Ascending sorte, in next click the descending sort, so on. And when the user used the Ctrl + click return to default state.

Can I create a custom sorting order in user click? For example:

First click -> ascending

Second click -> descending

Third click -> default order

Fourth click -> ascending

…

So on…

I'm using: DxGrid and DxGridDataColumn

[image]